# Variable input via App Printer Setup Zebra ZD421

Tags: variables, input, text, tablet, zebra-printers

My name is Reinhard and I am from Austria. I am looking for help for my printer settings.

I use the translator sometimes, I hope you understand what I mean.

With the Zebra ZD421, is it possible to enter a variable date using the Zebra App Printer Setup (Android)?

I still have a ZT231. With the correct settings in ZDesigner I am asked for a date before printing. (In the printer, in the app or in the web browser).

I use ZDesigner 3.
With the ZT231, I use the tablet (larger screen) to select the correct print template using the printer app, enter the date and number and print the label.

I want to do the same with the ZD421.

I hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Best regards
Reinhard